# Commandline tool for comprehensive and integrated testing of internet connectivity

Tags: command-line, internet

Is there a commandline tool for GNU/Linux which will analyse download and upload speed, packet-loss, latency and other factors which will indicate internet connectivity status?

Comment: I'm not sure if this of interest, but [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/iftop/) shows bandwidth usage.

Comment: @Faheem Mitha, if your comment was an answer I'd upvote it! *hint hint*

Comment: @kce: Have at it. :-)

Comment: See also [How to test Internet connection speed from command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426272/how-to-test-internet-connection-speed-from-command-line) (only covers download; for upload you'll need some server's cooperation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/iftop/) to show bandwidth usage.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `ping`, `netstat` or `traceroute`. You'll find a small introduction [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-networkperfanalysis/index.html).